# Disable Sticky Nav when on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to disable my Sticky Navbar when on Mobile. Please have a look at my JS Fiddle `Visit`http://jsfiddle.net/iolo/0pjrvumm/1/

I have a media query set at 400px. **When loading the page on a window greater than 400px** the sticky navbar works great and when I resize it to less than 400px without refreshing the browser the mobile navbar also works great.

**When I load the page in a window less than 400px** the mobile navbar works as planned. However the problem I am having is when I resize the window to more than 400px without refreshing the browser. The navbar will jump to the top when I begin to scroll and does not function as it normally did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that when you are on a mobile device (If you open it in mobile) then initially you do `var stickyNavTop = $('#main-nav-wrapper-sticky').offset().top;`

HOWEVER since `$('#main-nav-wrapper-sticky')` has `display:none` (due to your media query <`400px`) then `stickyNavTop` is set to `0` which is causing all of your issue, since you never resize your header nav why not just hard code it to `var stickyNavTop = 108`?

OR force it to display:block (`$('#sticky-nav-placeholder').css({ 'display': 'block'});`) and then call `var stickyNavTop = $('#main-nav-wrapper-sticky').offset().top;` then determine if under 400px and re hide it if that is true.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var stickyNavTop = 108; // Since you never change the height

    var stickyNav = function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
            $('#main-nav-wrapper-sticky').css('position','fixed');
            $('#main-nav-wrapper-sticky').css('top','0');
            $('#sticky-nav-placeholder').css({ 'display': 'block'});
        }
        else {
            $('#main-nav-wrapper-sticky').css('position','relative');
            $('#sticky-nav-placeholder').css({ 'display': 'none'}); 
        }
        };

    stickyNav();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0pjrvumm/11/

Comment: As simple as that! thanks a lot for your help and the clear explanation. I ended up hardcoding the stickyNavTop because like you said that will never change. Thank you again for your help Simply Graig.